# SQL - Value difference between specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query is as follows

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(TimePeriod,6) Period, -- string field with YYYYMMDD
    SUM(Value) Value
FROM 
    f_Trans_GL
WHERE 
    Account = 228
GROUP BY 
    TimePeriod
```

And it returns

```
Period   Value
---------------
201412    80
201501    20
201502    30
201506    50
201509   100
201509   100
```

I'd like to know the Value difference between rows where the period is 1 month apart. The calculation being [value period] - [value period-1].

The desired output being;

```
Period   Value   Calculated
-----------------------------------
201412    80      80 - null = 80
201501    20      20 - 80 = -60
201502    30      30 - 20 = 10
201506    50      50 - null = 50
201509   100     (100 + 100) - null = 200
```

This illustrates a second challenge, as the period needs to be evaluated if the year changes (the difference between 201501 and 201412 is one month).

And the third challenge being a duplicate Period (201509), in which case the sum of that period needs to be evaluated.

Any indicators on where to begin, if this is possible, would be great!

Thanks in advance

===============================

After I accepted the answer, I tailored this a little to suit my needs, the end result is:

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT

  ISNULL(CAST(TransactionID AS nvarchar), '_nullTransactionId_') + ISNULL(Description, '_nullDescription_') + CAST(Account AS nvarchar) + Category + Currency + Entity + Scenario AS UID,

  LEFT(TimePeriod, 6) Period,
  SUM(Value1) Value1,
  CAST(LEFT(TimePeriod, 6) + '01' AS date) ord_date
FROM MyTestTable
GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod, 6),
         TransactionID,
         Description,
         Account,
         Category,
         Currency,
         Entity,
         Scenario,
         TimePeriod)
SELECT
  a.UID,
  a.Period,
  --a.Value1,
  ISNULL(a.Value1, 0) - ISNULL(b.Value1, 0) Periodic
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.ord_date = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, b.ord_date)
ORDER BY a.UID
```

I have to get the new value (Periodic) for each UID. This UID must be determined as done here because the PK on the table won't work.

But the issue is that this will return many more rows than I actually have to begin with in my table. If I don't add a GROUP BY and ORDER by UID (as done above), I can tell that the first result for each combination of UID and Period is actually correct, the subsequent rows for that combination, are not.

I'm not sure where to look for a solution, my guess is that the UID is the issue here, and that it will somehow iterate over the field... any direction appreciated.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Why not `GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod,6)`?

Comment: For `201507` shouldn't the value be `200`

Comment: LEFT(TimePeriod,6) works actually

Comment: for 201507 the value in the table is 100 for each 201507 row, but the calculated value is indeed 200

Comment: @HendrikKleine  Why is the value in 201507 not subtracting the 50 from 201506?

Comment: @iamdave - mistake in my sample! Updated to 201509.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by other, first mistake is in `Group by` you need to `Left(timeperiod, 6`) instead of `timeperiod`.

For remaining calculation try something like this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT LEFT(timeperiod, 6)                      Period, 
                Sum(value)                               Value, 
                Cast(LEFT(timeperiod, 6) + '01' AS DATE) ord_date 
         FROM   f_trans_gl 
         WHERE  account = 228 
         GROUP  BY LEFT(timeperiod, 6)) 
SELECT a.period, 
       a.value, 
       a.value - Isnull(b.value, 0) 
FROM   cte a 
       LEFT JOIN cte b 
              ON a.ord_date = Dateadd(month, 1, b.ord_date)
```

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012` then this can be easily done using `LAG` analytic function

Comment: The period comparison in monthly, so you need to add a month and not a day in your `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Prdp & iamdave - tested perfectly, impressive! Thank you

Comment: @Prdp - I added some code (see revised question) to yours to make it work for me, but evidently my original use case here was incomplete since I wasn't able to make it work. Any thoughts on where I can look as a starting point?

Comment: @HendrikKleine - Please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a derived table, you can join the data to itself to find rows that are in the preceding period.  I have converted your `Period` to a `Date` value so you can use SQL Server's `dateadd` function to check for rows in the previous month:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 
    LEFT(TimePeriod,6) Period, -- string field with YYYYMMDD
    CAST(TimePeriod + '01' AS DATE) PeriodDate
    SUM(Value) Value
FROM f_Trans_GL
WHERE Account = 228
GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod,6)
)
SELECT c1.Period,
    c1.Value,
    c1.Value - ISNULL(c2.Value,0) AS Calculation
FROM cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2
        ON c1.PeriodDate = DATEADD(m,1,c2.PeriodDate)
```

Comment: Ha this is a duplicate of my answer ;)

Comment: @Prdp Great minds and all that, though I did get `join` condition right ;D

Answer (score 0):

Without cte, you can also try something like this

```
SELECT A.Period,A.Value,A.Value-ISNULL(B.Value) Calculated
FROM
(
    SELECT LEFT(TimePeriod,6) Period
    DATEADD(M,-1,(CONVERT(date,LEFT(TimePeriod,6)+'01'))) PeriodDatePrev,SUM(Value) Value
    FROM f_Trans_GL
    WHERE Account = 228
    GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod,6)
) AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT LEFT(TimePeriod,6) Period
    (CONVERT(date,LEFT(TimePeriod,6)+'01')) PeriodDate,SUM(Value) Value
    FROM f_Trans_GL
    WHERE Account = 228
    GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod,6)
) AS B
ON (A.PeriodDatePrev = B.PeriodDate)
ORDER BY 1
```